# "New Approval Step" button missing in Approval Process related List?

Tags: approval-process

"New Approval Step" button missing in Approval Process related List.
As per the help, if the approval process is active then this button is not available. But the issue is even after deactivating the approval process the "New Approval Step" button is missing. Anything I am missing?
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The message you get when activating starts with:

> After activating this approval process, you cannot add or remove
>   approval steps.

and the platform appears to enforce that whether or not instances of the approval process are in use.

So I think cloning to a new name is the only choice. (You can then delete the original one if there are no instances of it.) We just append a number to our approval process names when we have new versions.

Comment: Thanks @Keith C.. I tried your cloning option and it is working....