# Editing Already created approval process

Tags: administration, approval-process

In salesforce, we can not add any step to an approval process once it is activated. Is there any way to edit approval process(Adding new Steps and doing some other changes) after it is activated. Salesforce does not allow us to edit even if we deactivate the process and then try to add step. I know It is mentioned in salesforce documentation that we can not add a step to approval process once it is deactivated. But if someone knows any adavnced way of doing that using some code, then please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See e.g. [“New Approval Step” button missing in Approval Process related List?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32027/new-approval-step-button-missing-in-approval-process-related-list).

Comment: @KeithC Thank you, I was not aware of the fact the cloning also copies steps. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for this problem is that we can clone already created approval process, then we can do modification in new cloned approval process(Adding steps).

Answer (score 1):

You cant add a step to the approval process once it has been activated. You can duplicate the add the step by cloning and renaming the process. Just call it the same process but edit the unique name if you need it for recognition.